# HTML form not forwarding to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to forward my html form (id=application) but the server is returning 
status: undefined
response: undefined
query: undefined

This is the part of the code below.

```
<script>
        function sendForm(){
            var form = $("#application");
            $.post("send-mail.php",form.serialize(),function(data){
                console.log("status : " + data.status);
                console.log("response : " + data.message);
                console.log("query : " + data.query);
                }
            });
</script>
```

What could be wrong with it?

Comment: Ok, your title says `HTML form not forwading to server`, but then you say `but the server is returning...` Can you try and write the question again as it's not very clear at the moment what your question actually is

Comment: Does the server send `Content-type: application/json` header?

Comment: How is this a php question? there's no code for it. Not to mention the form. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the server sends the `Content-type: application/json` header, jQuery won't automatically parse the response as JSON. You need to tell jQuery to do this by adding a datatype parameter to `$.post`:

```
        $.post("send-mail.php",form.serialize(),function(data){
            console.log("status : " + data.status);
            console.log("response : " + data.message);
            console.log("query : " + data.query);
            }
        }, "json");
```

Comment: I tried this and now I'm not getting any response and not receiving the email at the same time, I'm not sure if I'm not doing it correctly but I added , "json" like you did there is there something else I need to do?

Comment: My answer doesn't change what's sent to the server or how the server sends the mail, only how the response is processed.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Dev Tools to see the parameters that are being sent and the response being received. Also check your PHP error log on the server.